# Google Sheets onEdit uppercase script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm collecting one-letter responses from users in a Google Sheet and would like their responses to be made uppercase as they are input, but only within the cells D5-J[infinity]. I found a few responses on how to do this and Frankensteined the following code in Script Editor, but it's not firing. What's wrong?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();

  if ( col >=  4 && col <= 10 ) {
    if ( row >= 5 ) {
      if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
        e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you collecting the responses? Are the users directly typing them in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, Ruben. But it doesn't matter because I figured it out myself :):)
The problem was that I was using two different sources for my code. One used the variable col and the other used column. Works like a charm now :)

Comment: Please post  the fix you mention as an answer.

Comment: At the bottom of this page there is a "Post your answer" button. Use it to post your solution if you think that it will be helpful for someone else. If you think that it will not be helpful for anyone, you could delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the problem was just that I defined the variable for the columns as "column" but then used a different variable in the code: "col". Simple user error. :)

The correct formula is as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();

  if ( column >=  4 && col <= 10 ) {
    if ( row >= 5 ) {
      if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
        e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
      }
    }
  }
}
```